# Long figure caption breaks layout

Tags: bootstrap-5

Please look at the screenshots: the code is exactly the same, I've only cut the figure caption short. The image and caption are supposed to float to the right but I can't make the caption wrap under the photo only.

[image]
[image]

Here's my code:

```
<div class="col-12">
        <figure class="figure float-end">
        <img class="img-fluid shadow ms-3 mb-2" src="/images/<?php echo $pageImage; ?>" alt="<?php echo $pageImage; ?>" />
        <figcaption class="small ms-3 mb-2"><?php echo (isset($pageDesc)? $pageDesc : ""); ?></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <ul class="list-group border-0 p-1">
        <?php echo $text; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I've tried removing or chaning the margin classes, adding `float-end` to the caption – nothing helps.

EDIT: I found out that this behaviour had been reported as a Bootstrap bug but was dismissed (?). The reporting user, however, proposed a fix which I implemented and now it does the magic.

I will leave this question open for other solutions that do not require overriding the native bootstrap styles.

Comment: This is just a guess at the moment but it could easily work...... Try adding `text-wrap` to the Class for `<figcaption>` so that it reads `<figcaption class="small ms-3 mb-2 text-wrap">` ......  `text-wrap` is a standard Bootstrap Class.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob, Thanks, I just tried it – doesn't do the magic :(

Comment: A bit annoying since that is the exact purpose of `text-wrap`. Just because Bootstrap like to be a little odd sometimes and as a test, try adding the `text-wrap` to `<figure>` instead of `<figcaption>` ........ Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Nope :( no joy either.

Comment: I just found out somebody reported this as a bug in Bootstrap but the report was scrapped with no solution offered: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29492

Comment: But the fix that the user reporting the issue provided did the trick! However, a native bootstrap solution would be nice to have.